# PyQt4 ---- I want to use closeEvent() in my code

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qmessagebox

I am python newbie. I am developing pr-room management program.
I think if the user presses the x button , i want to give a warning message . 
So, I want to use closeEvent() in first code.
In other words, first code + second code please

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\PJH11\Desktop\dia3.ui'
#
# Created: Sun Aug 17 16:23:08 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(190, 98)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 191, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "hi", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

```
def closeEvent(self, event):

    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
        "Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
        QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can implement your class to create  `closeEvent` (As your code close event), put them it and create object in main. And your can call to close event by using `bool QWidget.close (self)`.

Full example;

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.Dialog = Dialog
        self.Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("self.Dialog"))
        self.Dialog.resize(190, 98)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 191, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.retranslateUi(self.Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self.Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('released()'), self.Dialog.close) # <- put signal to close when clicked.

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        self.Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("self.Dialog", "self.Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("self.Dialog", "hi", None))

class QCustomDialog (QtGui.QDialog): # <- Implement your own
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
            QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QCustomDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Regards,